# Create default value variable of template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following summation template function as an example:

```
template <typename T>
T Sum(std::vector<T>& source)
{
    T v;
    for (auto it = source.begin(); it != source.end(); ++it)
    {
        v += *it;
    }
    return v;
}
```

This works for custom types which define the `+=` operator, but how can I also have it work for primitive types, e.g. `float`?

The line `T v;` will yield an uninitialized value.

Using `T v = 0;` will work for `float`, but will not work for non primitives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just initialize `v`.

```
T v = T();
```

or in C++11 just

```
T v{};
```

Answer (score 3):

You could value-initialize rather than default-initialize:

```
T v{};
```

This will call the default constructor for class types and zero-initialize built-in types.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it is not C++11 so I'll have to stick with the other solution.